# Python open(file, "rb").read() nondeterministically returns empty string

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, file-io, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running a Python3 script through Ansible (on Ubuntu WSL). However, I got some weird behavior of Python's `open().read()`  which sometimes returns an empty string. It's not always the case, but sometimes it randomly returns an empty string. Sometimes I had to run & re-run the Ansible script for about 3 or 4 times to reproduce this weird behavior.

Here's a snippet of the weird output:

```
...
Converting 1: /mnt/h/.../some-file.yml 203
Converting 2-0: /mnt/h/.../some-file.yml 0
Converting 3: /mnt/h/.../some-file.yml 203
Converted: /mnt/h/.../some-file.yml 203
...
```

Please pay attention to the `Converting 2-0: <PATH> 0` which means the `len(content) == 0` (I expect it to be `203` just like the other output-lines). This is printed by the:

```
...

with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
    f.seek(0)
    content = f.read()
    f.close()

for i in range(3):
    print(f"Converting 2-{i}: {file_path} {len(content)}")
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        f.seek(0)
        content = f.read()
        f.close()
    if len(content) != 0:
        break

print(f"Converting 3: {file_path} {len(content)}")
...
```

That means that the first `open().read()` does return an empty string, meanwhile the second `open().read()` returns correctly. No write actions were performed between them.

I tried to run the same script on Windows multiple times, but this problem didn't occur.

If you care for the full picture of my script, here's my script:

Here's my ansible playbook:

```
- name: Main
  hosts: all
  become: True
  vars:
    parent_directory: "{{ inventory_dir | dirname }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "python3 ./data/convert-all-crlf-to-lf.py \"{{parent_directory}}\""
    - name: convert all ansible-related file to LF end-of-line
      command: "python3 ./data/convert-all-crlf-to-lf.py \"{{parent_directory}}\" 2>&1"
      delegate_to: "localhost"
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result
    ... (some other more commands)
```

convert-all-crlf-to-lf.py:

```
import os.path
import sys
import warnings


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        raise ValueError("Require 1 argument: path of file/folder to be converted to LF end-of-line")
    rootdir = sys.argv[1]

    if os.path.isfile(rootdir):
        convert_to_LF_EOL(rootdir)
        return
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            file_full_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            convert_to_LF_EOL(file_full_path)


TEXTCHARS = bytearray({7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 27} | set(range(0x20, 0x100)) - {0x7f})


def is_binary_string(string: bytes):
    return bool(string.translate(None, TEXTCHARS))


def is_binary_file(file_path: str, read_block_size=10 * 1024 * 1024):
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        content = f.read()
    print(f"Converting 1: {file_path} {len(content)}")

    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            content = f.read(read_block_size)
            if is_binary_string(content):
                return True
            if content == b'':
                break
    return False


def convert_to_LF_EOL(file_path: str):
    assert os.path.isfile(file_path)
    if is_binary_file(file_path):
        warnings.warn(f"\n Skipping... Detected as a binary file: {file_path} \n", stacklevel=2)
        return
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        f.seek(0)
        content = f.read()
        f.close()

    for i in range(3):
        print(f"Converting 2-{i}: {file_path} {len(content)}")
        with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
            f.seek(0)
            content = f.read()
            f.close()
        if len(content) != 0:
            break

    print(f"Converting 3: {file_path} {len(content)}")
    content = content.replace(b"\r\n", b"\n")

    with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(content)
    print(f"Converted: {file_path} {len(content)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**TLDR:**
How this is even possible? I've fixed the bad outcome caused by this issue, but I'm still curious why this is even possible.

Comment: Where's the `Converting 1: ...`  output coming from? Also, probably unrelated, but get rid of `f.seek(0)` and `f.close()` - those are implicit.

Comment: @Gaberocksall For the `Converting 1: ...` it's printed inside the `is_binary_file` function, in the complete Python script I attached. You're right, `f.seek(0)` and `f.close()` should be implicitly done by the `with ...`, but that's what makes it even more confusing because I already explicitly `close()` and `seek(0)` but the `.read()` still returns empty string sometimes 